# Automation of changing permission of Azure DevOps repository for a security group

Tags: azure, devops, azure-devops-rest-api

I want to write a PowerShell code to change permission of a ]Azure DevOps repository for a security group Manual process is documented in this article.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/set-git-repository-permissions?view=azure-devops)

[image]
[image]

Please help me with above.

Comment: Hi Denuwan, have you checked jessehowwing's answer, does it work for you? :)

Answer (score 0):

[I've blogged about the process on how to do this](https://jessehouwing.net/azure-devops-git-setting-default-repository-permissions/), not on the REST API perse, but using the `az devops` CLI.

The process is quite complex, since the permission model of Azure DevOps uses GUIDs and tokens for the permissions, users and access control list items.

`az devops` calls the REST API under the hood, you could use fiddler to have a peek at the REST calls that are made to achieve the same thing.

The general process looks like this:

```
$subject = az devops security group list `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --scope organization `
    --subject-types vssgp `
    --query "graphGroups[?@.principalName == '[$org]\Project Collection Administrators'].descriptor | [0]"
    
$namespaceId = az devops security permission namespace list `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --query "[?@.name == 'Git Repositories'].namespaceId | [0]"

$bit = az devops security permission namespace show `
    --namespace-id $namespaceId `
    --org "https://dev.azure.com/$org/" `
    --query "[0].actions[?@.name == 'PullRequestBypassPolicy'].bit | [0]"

az devops security permission update `
    --id $namespaceId `
    --subject $subject `
    --token "repoV2/" `
    --allow-bit $bit `
    --merge true `
    --org https://dev.azure.com/$org/
```

The token is made up of a number of identifiers:

```
repoV2/daec401a-49b6-4758-adb5-3f65fd3264e3/f59f38e0-e8c4-45d5-8dee-0d20e7ada1b7/refs/heads/6600650061007400750072006500/6d0069006e006500
^      ^                                    ^                                    ^
|      |                                    |                                    |
|      |                                    |                                    -- The branch
|      |                                    -- The Git Repository
|      -- The Team Project Guid
|
-- The root object (Repositories)
```

This sets the permissions for all git repos, the blog contains the code to generate a `--token` for a specific branch:

```
function hexify($string) {
     return ($string | Format-Hex -Encoding Unicode | Select-Object -Expand Bytes | ForEach-Object { '{0:x2}' -f $_ }) -join ''
}

$branch = "feature/mine"
$split = $branch.Split("/")
$hexBranch = ($split | ForEach-Object { hexify -string $_ }) -join "/"
$token = "refs/heads/$hexBranch"

refs/heads/6600650061007400750072006500/6d0069006e006500
```